# Linking C++ static Library in C using gcc

Tags: c++, c, gcc, g++

In the following code, I am trying to call a dummy function written in C++ (using C++ header files like ap_fixed.h, ap_int.h) from a C function. The code runs fine when I compile with g++. But when I use gcc for compiling test.c, it throws an error because I have included a C++ header file which is a valid error.

Is there any workaround to compile using gcc? I have read from some posts that it is not a good practice to merge C/C++ code in this manner. Please enlighten me if there are any serious repurcussions of working with a large C codebase and doing similar stuff.

Thanks

Header File: testcplusplus.h

```
#include "ap_fixed.h"
#include "ap_int.h"

#ifdef __cplusplus
extern "C" {
#endif

void print_cplusplus();

#ifdef __cplusplus
}
#endif
```

testcplusplus.cc

```
#include <iostream>
#include "testcplusplus.h"

void print_cplusplus() {

ap_ufixed<10, 5,AP_RND_INF,AP_SAT > Var1 = 22.96875; 
std::cout << Var1 << std::endl;
}
```

test.c

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include "testcplusplus.h"

int main() {
print_cplusplus();
}
```

Commands Used:

```
g++ -c -o testcplusplus.o testcplusplus.cc 
ar rvs libtest.a testcplusplus.o
gcc -o test test.c -L. -ltest
```

Error:

```
In file included from ap_fixed.h:21:0,
                 from testcplusplus.h:1,
                 from test.c:2:
ap_int.h:21:2: error: #error C++ is required to include this header file
```

Comment: You can specify the input language with `gcc -x c++`

Comment: Not related to your immediate problem, but you should include `testcplusplus.h` in `testcplusplus.c` (which should probably have the extension `.cc` or `.cpp`, to ensure that it is recognized as a C++ file).

Comment: Also: if there's any C++ in the executable, `main` should be in C++.  (Although I don't know if modern implementations still require this.)

Comment: You still need to link the C++ runtime, at least, surely.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem here is that the C++ header ap_fixed.h is included from the C program test.c (indirectly via testcplusplus.h).

The solution is to remove the include of headers "ap_fixed.h"
and "ap_int.h" from testcplusplus.h and include them directly from testcplusplus.cpp. The C program doesn't need to know about these anyway, only the C++ wrapper uses them directly.

In a larger example it might be appropriate to split testcplusplus.h into two headers: one that contains only declarations of the external interface you are presenting to the C environment, and another containing the rest - declarations needed internally in the C++ implementation and any required includes.

Once you have done this, you will still face linking errors because the executable that is produced will contain references to symbols from the C++ runtime libraries, plus any other libraries that your C++ code uses. To solve this, add -l directives when compiling the final executable, eg:

```
gcc -o test test.c -L. -ltest -lstdc++
```

Comment: I used your suggestions sir but was still getting some errors. I had to use -lstdc++ option along with gcc to successfully compile test.c

Comment: OK, thats another aspect: the executable needs to be linked to the standard C++ libs, otherwise you will get undefined references. I will add that to the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You do not need to include *ap_int.h* and *ap_fixed.h* at this point, as the declaration of the `print_cplusplus` function does not need those definitions.

Rather, include them in *testcplusplus.c*, so the C compiler can only see the C compatible interface of the C++ code.